# Get temperature from string with regex

Tags: php, regex

I could really use som help getting the temperature value out of this string:

> "type=sensor  protocol=fineoffset model=temperaturehumidity   id=135  temperature=26.5    humidity=49 time=2014-07-01
> 21:03:24  age=29"

I figured that you can write a regex that takes the value between termperature= and \s to get the numeric value. I've tried this but I couldnt get the hang of it.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Something simple like `temperature\s*=\s*(\S+)\s` might work for you. See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yG4gQ2/1).

Comment: Tried this with no luck (?<=temperature=)(.*)(?= humidity).

Will try your advice @AmalMurali. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with this small snippet

```
temperature\s*=\s*\K(?<temperature>\d+(?:\.\d+))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/LPxXUdGQhmW7Ab-O)

It will give you in the response array the key `temperature` with your wanted value

Answer (score 0):

`.*?temperature=(.*?)`

there's a space: " " at the end of `(.*?)` in the regex

Answer (score 0):

Try matching this:

`temperature=(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

Then simply return `\1`